# Multiple forms are being opened c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want a form to be opened when the condition is met. The second form opens but the problem is that multiple forms are being opened. I don't know what seems to be the problem even after i put break points.
this is the code

```
if (lives == 0 || score == 80)
{
    FrmHallOfFame hOf = new FrmHallOfFame(true);
    hOf.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple forms"? Exactly 5? Up to 10? Many more? Which forms? The one you want to open? Or the parent?

Comment: What "multiple forms are being opened" problem really is? Is that exception or what?

Comment: the FrmHallOfFame which is the form i want it to open when the condition is true. I do not know how many times the form is being opened but it is repeatedly  being opened several times

Comment: Don't worry set break point and check what will happen.it goes to form2 and when you close that it will go this line  `this.Close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShowDialog **blocks** the until the opened form is closed. Which means the code *after* ShowDialog is not executed untill you close it.

```
if (lives == 0 || score == 80)
{
    FrmHallOfFame hOf = new FrmHallOfFame(true);
    hOf.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: @MariaApap - Consider upvoting / accepting answer if it worked for your. It would be helpful for other users also